# FullCalendar how to resize time axis for Vaadin

Tags: fullcalendar, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am using the Full Calendar plugin component.

The time-axis is super cramped and does not look good in my language.

[image]

How do I set the width of the time-axis to e.g. 100px?

Code example:

```
FullCalendar calendar = FullCalendarBuilder.create().build();
    calendar.changeView(CalendarViewImpl.TIME_GRID_WEEK);
    calendar.setLocale(new Locale("da", "DK"));
```

Comment: You will have to use CSS. Open the dev tools and inspect the DOM

Comment: I found this <th aria-hidden="true" class="fc-timegrid-axis fc-scrollgrid-shrink"><div class="fc-timegrid-axis-frame fc-scrollgrid-shrink-frame fc-timegrid-axis-frame-liquid"><a class="fc-timegrid-axis-cushion fc-scrollgrid-shrink-cushion fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">Uge 20</a></div></th> and if I play with the CSS in the firefox inspect tool. I find that changing this: .fc .fc-timegrid-axis-frame {} it works. But if I add it to my own css-file in Vaadin. I do not experience any changes.